# Swift 3 generic type function to clamp numeric values into 0 and 1 interval

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I want to write a function that clamps a numeric value into the closed 0,1 interval:

```
func clamp01<T:???>(_ value:T) -> T {
  return value < 0 ? 0 : value > 1 ? 1 : value
}
```

In Swift 3 if I use `T:Strideable` I get a complaint that 0 and 1 must be typecast (`0 as! T` resolves the issue, but it's a forced cast).

In Swift 4 I may be able to use `T:Numeric` but I haven't tried that -- I am looking for a solution in Swift 3.

Comment: I believe you can use `Number` for this. Possibly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the function for all `Comparable` types which 
are also `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`, that covers all integer
and floating point types:

```
func clamp01<T: Comparable & ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>(_ value: T) -> T { 
    return value < 0 ? 0 : value > 1 ? 1 : value
}
```